# Access viewer methods from AggregatedView for more than one model in Autodesk Forge Viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am loading two different models via AggregatedView.
Although I have access to `view.viewer`, executing

```js
var view = new Autodesk.Viewing.AggregatedView();
//...
view.viewer.isolate([0]);
```

only affects one of the two models.

Is there any way I can call viewer methods such as isolate(), show(), hide(), etc. on both models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that many of the `Viewer3D` methods such as [Viewer3D#isolate](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#isolate-node-model) accept an additional parameter that you can use to specify the model.

And if the method you're interested in doesn't accept the model as one of its parameters, you can often find the same method directly on the `Model` class, for example, [Model#getProperties](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Model/#getproperties-dbid-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback).